# 3NF normalization assistance

Tags: database, relational-database, database-normalization, 3nf

I have the following relational database with FDS:
R1 (ABCDEFGH)
FDs: AB --> D, B --> C, B --> E, B --> F, A --> H, H --> G

I think the key is AB.

I decomposed this down to R1(BCEF) and R2(ABDGH).  Then I decomposed R2 down to R3(AH) and R4(ABDG).

I need somebody to double-check me, because I think I'm making a mistake here, but I'm not sure what it is.  I seem to have lost the H --> G FD in the decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

At a quick glance you the relation can be decomposed to 3NF preserving all 6 FDs

## At least 2NF (No partial dependencies)

- R1(**A**, H, G) = FD5, FD6
- R2(**B**, C, E, F) = FD2, FD3, FD4
- R3(**A, B**, D) = FD1

## At least 3NF (No transitive dependencies)

- R1(**A**, H) = FD5
- R2(**H**, G) = FD6
- R3(**B**, C, E, F) = FD2, FD3, FD4
- R4(**A, B**, D) = FD1

Also I have heard that removing redundant FD is not a bad thing ;)